# HTML href container.dataiteim

Tags: html, asp.net

I have the following code.

I get an error in the cases where the "mail" column has not been added to the dataset.

How would I code to get a default value in the case the column "mail" is not present in the dataset?

```
<a href="mailto:<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "mail") %>
```

Comment: I think you forgot your code ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="mailto:<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "mail") != null ? DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "mail") : "default@default.com"%>
```